# Teamcity Nuget Feed is not showing latest package version

Tags: nuget, teamcity, octopus-deploy

I tried to find the solution of my problem on google, many blogs and tried many suggestion but nothing is working.

My problem is like this:
TeamCity Solution Build is creating artifact and publishing it but the package version is not showing in visual studio package Manager Console and not even in Octopus Library External Feed test. Because of this all my builds are failing as octopus is not able to find the latest package which is being generated in the current build.

I dont remember making any change in setting or configuration of teamcity or octopus and this issue came up suddenly. Before this everything was working fine.

Can someone please help me in solving this issue as I'm stuck here?

I have already found an alternative which can be to push packages to Octopus repository and use the package from there but I dont want to change the configurations now and trying to fix this issue first.